Can porcelain tile that has been set with thinset for 24 hrs be replaced before grouting?
Can 1 piece of polished porcelain tile that was chipped while removing the plastic spacers be replaced? It has been set on a shower wall for 24 hours with mortar. No grout yet.


I mean, you can chip it off.  You are probably unlikely to get it off nondestructively, though.  Maybe with a cable saw (and a lot of elbow grease) you could cut through the thinset.  Or are you asking about removing one tile in a field of other tiles that have already been set?

Is the chip bad enough that the grout will not cover it(into the face)?

I want to remove 1 tile in a field of other tiles that have already been set (no grout) don't care about damaging the chipped tile.

It is up to to you, but seems small enough for a bit extra grout would not stand out that much.  Depending on the colour of the grout.  The extra grout would only make it about 0.1% from 100% perfect.

Absolutely. Tiles are replaced individually all the time. The trick is to get it off without damaging adjacent tiles or the backer.
A good way to do this is to cut or break into the tile at the middle so you don't pry on the other tiles at all. Those edges are fragile, as you've learned.
When you get near the other tiles, don't damage them by lifting the tile you're removing. Wood shims in the grout joint might help protect them.
Once it's off, grind down any mortar lumps so you have a reasonably flat surface. Apply mortar to the back of the new tile more thinly than you would with a bare wall so it's not sticking out from the others. It might take some experimenting to get right.
See also How can I remove a single cracked floor tile? and How do you replace a couple tiles?

You have an answer regarding removal. However you should consider just touching up the chip.
Before grouting you can use a porcelain repair kit to cover the chip.
Then after grouting and cleaning, touch up the mark with a touch up paint..
Since the tile has a marbled look, a touch up can be well hidden as another vein of the marble.
I have done just this same thing in my bathroom.  The touch up is imperceptible.
